# PHP MySQL Loop Not working

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Okay so I've been trying to setup a for loop for my testimonials to be put into the website but I can't get the loop to work.

```
    <?php            
    $count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM testimonials");

    for ($i = 1; $i <= intval($count['cnt']); $i++)
    {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'testimonials' WHERE id='{$i}'");
        ?>
        <li class="span4">
            <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-1">
                <section> 
                    <a class="link-1" style="cursor:pointer;"><?php echo $sql['name']; ?></a>
                    <p><?php echo $sql['text']; ?></p>
                    <a href="http:// <?php echo $sql['product']; ?> /" class="link-1"><?php echo $sql['website']; ?></a>
                </section>
            </div>
        </li>

        <?php
        }

    ?>
```

All the database column names are correct.

top.php (included fine)

```
require_once('/home/redjaxco/public_html/admin/owa_php.php');

$owa = new owa_php();
// Set the site id you want to track
$owa->setSiteId('4ca8477d56738edbe0eec3485abce08b');
$owa->trackPageView();

// Database connect
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'redjaxco';
$db_pass        = '*******';
$db_database    = 'redjaxco_website'; 

$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish a DB     connection');

mysql_select_db($db_database,$link);
mysql_query("SET names UTF8");


?>
```

Comment: `var_dump(intval($count['cnt']))` most likely returns `0`

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: You're not doing any error checking on your queries. Do you know which one isn't working? Do you know why it isn't working?

Comment: dont you need a mysql_fetch_array? And dont use mysql_ functions it was deprecated.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you never call mysql_connect(); did you do that in your code and not include it here? If you don't call it, mysql_query behaves as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. The default values for host, user, and password are 'localhost:3306', mysql.default_user, and mysql.default_password. Sources: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: I do that in a top.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need **mysql_fetch_assoc**. But I would suggest you moving to use **PDO** or **MySQLi** since **MySql_*** has been deprecated.

Your **$count** variable returns **0** because you are trying to cast it into int but it holds an object.

So you would do something like:

```
   $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($count);
   for ($i = 1; $i < intval($data['cnt']); $i++) {
     ....
   }
```

Comment: Okay that's kinda worked, its got the item now showing but not the content

Comment: The $sql variables aren't getting a value is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to fetch some data from your queries:

```
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM testimonials");
 $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
 $count = $r['cnt'];
```

And:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'testimonials' WHERE id='{$i}'");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
  print_r($row);
}
```

**EDIT:**

As GGio mentioned, consider using `PDO` as `mysql_*` commands are [depreciated](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php).

Comment: "PDO and the PDO_SQLITE driver is enabled by default as of PHP 5.1.0. You may need to enable the PDO driver for your database of choice..." http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php